# My link starts to levitate in gazebo

Tags: control, gazebo, ros2

I'm developing a gazebo robot and I have an upper torso (upper_body_link) that needs tilting (with revolute joint 'upper_body_joint').

the problem is that when running the launch file in the gazebo with nothing else in parallel, the upper_body starts to levitate as can be seen in the images below.

[image]
[image]

I really don't understand what's happend, but it's the upper that goes up and no the lower that goes down.

In attached i send the urdf file for the robot, the ros2_control files

URDF FILE:

```
<xacro:include filename="inertial_macros.xacro"/>
<xacro:include filename="ros2_control.xacro"/>

<material name="white">
    <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
</material>
<material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0.2 0.2 1 1"/>
</material>
<material name="black">
    <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
</material>
<material name="red">
    <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
</material>
<material name="grey">
    <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1"/>
</material>

<!--BASE LINK-->
<link name="base_link">
</link>

<!--BASE FOOTPRINT LINK-->
<joint name="base_footprint_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base_footprint"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<link name="base_footprint">
</link>

<!--CHASSI-->
<joint name="chassi_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="chassi_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/> <!--VIRADO PARA X-->
    <!--<origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 ${pi/2}"/> VIRADO PARA Y-->
</joint>

<link name="chassi_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.085"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.275" length="0.334"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.085"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.275" length="0.17"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="1.0" length="0.17" radius="0.275">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.085" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
</link>

<gazebo reference="chassi_link">
    <material>Gazebo/White</material>
</gazebo>

<!--LOWER BODY-->
<joint name="lower_body_joint" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="lower_body_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.25" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit lower="0" upper="0.14" velocity="100" effort="100"/>
</joint>

<link name="lower_body_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.18" rpy="0 0 ${pi/2}"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.2 0.05 0.35"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.18" rpy="0 0 ${pi/2}"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.2 0.05 0.35"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_box mass="0.1" x="0.2" y="0.05" z="0.35">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.18" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_box>
</link>

<gazebo reference="lower_body_link">
    <material>Gazebo/White</material>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
</gazebo>

<!--UPPER BODY-->
<joint name="upper_body_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="lower_body_link"/>
    <child link="upper_body_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.355" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit lower="0.1745" upper="1.2217" velocity="100" effort="100"/>
</joint>
    
<link name="upper_body_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.25" rpy="0 0 ${pi/2}"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.2 0.05 0.50"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.25" rpy="0 0 ${pi/2}"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.2 0.05 0.50"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_box mass="0.03" x="0.2" y="0.05" z="0.50">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.25" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_box>
</link>

<gazebo reference="upper_body_link">
    <material>Gazebo/White</material>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
</gazebo>

<xacro:ros2_control_gazebo/>
```

ROS2_CONTROL:

```
<xacro:macro name="ros2_control_gazebo" params="">
    <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>

        <!--CAMERA-->
        <joint name="camera_joint_y">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">-0.548</param>
                <param name="max">0.548</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="camera_joint_z">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">-0.548</param>
                <param name="max">0.548</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>

        <!--BODY-->
        <joint name="upper_body_joint">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">0.1745</param>
                <param name="max">1.2217</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="lower_body_joint">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">0</param>
                <param name="max">0.14</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>
</xacro:macro>

<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
        <parameters>$(find charmie_bot)/config/controller_configuration.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

CONTROLLERS.YAML:

controller_manager:
ros__parameters:
update_rate: 100

```
joint_trajectory_controller:
  type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController
joint_state_broadcaster:
  type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
```

joint_trajectory_controller:
ros__parameters:
joints:
- camera_joint_y
- camera_joint_z
- upper_body_joint
- lower_body_joint
interface_name: position
command_interfaces:
- position
state_interfaces:
- position
- velocity

Do you guys have any idea how to resolve this bug?

Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your problem already?

I tried to get your robot running and apart from some missing joints (camera_joint_y, camera_joint_z) in the URDF it seems to work. (I use rolling distro, Gazebo classic)

What I realized it that Gazebo Classic does not solve the contact points properly, as you can see in the picture. More infos in the [official docs](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=physics_params&cat=physics)

[image]

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why you think the contact points with the ground plane are wrong? Note that the question author's cylinder visual geometry and collision geometry do not align. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I can't remember any more. I linked the docs where the contact points are not stable, maybe this was the case.